# How can I import JSON field data from mySql server into Hive table using sqoop

Tags: mysql, json, hive, sqoop

I have a table name `EmpData` in MySQL server with two field as `EmpID (INT)` and `Details (nvarchar)`. `Details` field contain JSON string like

```
{ "name": "Michel","address":{"house no":"12","street":"Johnson road","city":"New Delhi","country":"INDIA"}}

{ "name": "John","address":{"house no":"99","street":"Johnson road","city":"London","country":"UK"}}
```

I want to import `Details` field JSON data into hive table `EmpHiveStore` and query on hive table like

```
SELECT name,address.street from EmpHiveStore;
```

Is there any way to import JSON field data into Hive table using sqoop?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqoop's job here is to import data from RDBMS(*MySQL in your case*) to Hive.

You need to use sqoop import command for this

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/testdb \
--username root \
--password root \
--table EmpData \
--columns Details \
--hive-import \
--hive-table EmpHiveStore
```

This will create hive table if not exists. **Sqoop's job is done here**. Hive will store this data in the String. There is *no special JSON type* in Hive. So, you won't be able to perform query like

```
SELECT name,address.street from EmpHiveStore;
```

directly via hive.

You can get the location of data using

```
show create table EmpHiveStore;
```

You have only 1 column in your table and it has JSON data. So it's basically a JSON file in HDFS.

You want to query into nested JSON. You need another tool that allows you to perform queries like this. You can explore SQL query engine like [Drill](https://drill.apache.org/) and [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/sql/) for this.